# Where is the X509Store that, allegedly, implements IDisposable in .NET 4.5?

Tags: security, .net-4.5, x509certificate, msdn, x509certificate2

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that `X509Store` class implements `IDisposable` in .NET 4.5. This was not the case in earlier versions of .NET.

Even though I have Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013, all .Net versions installed, from 2.0 to 4.5.1, I can only see `X509Store` that looks like .NET 4 version in latest **System.dll** (v4.0.30319, aka .NET 4.5). VS Object Browser also shows that `X509Store` in **System.dll** v4.0.30319 does not implement `IDisposable` like MSDN article says it should.

What am I missing and how do I get `X509Store` from .NET 4.5? Is MSDN wrong? It would not be the first time, but still. Is there an obscure Windows Update KB fix for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first sight, it looks like that MSDN says the half-truth: Microsoft added `IDisposable` interface to the `X509Store` class only in 4.6 version, not earlier. You can easily check it by using this really useful diff list between 4.5.2 and 4.6 versions: [NET 4.5.2 vs 4.6 - System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespace](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/Media/Diff/NET452-NET46.html#system.security.cryptography.x509certificates).

But at the current moment [the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the following sentence in the "Remarks" section:

> For apps that target the .NET Framework 4.5.2 and earlier versions,
>   the X509Store class does not implement the IDisposable interface and
>   therefore does not have a Dispose method.

Comment: Much obliged for RTFM. So for pre-4.5.6. targets the Close() has to be called explicitly?

Comment: @takiysobi, exactly, I've checked 4.6 version's sources and [the `Dispose()` method contains only the `Close()` method call](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509store.cs,1f06ba85baf228c9,references).